# Derivative with respect to y for Jacobian matrix (Newton's Method)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, numerical-methods

I'm solving multiple equations using Newton's method.  I'm working out the Jacobian matrix, and as it's late my brain is a bit hazy on partial derivatives.  I have two equations:

$$f_{1}:\frac{x^2}{16}+\frac{y^2}{9}=1$$
$$f_{2}:y=x^2-2x-4$$

I've worked out the derivatives, worked out the inverse, plugged my $x_{0}$ and $y_{0}$, but my answer is converging to something else - not where the intercepts are.

I take it something is wrong with my derivatives:

$$\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\delta x} = \frac{x}{8},\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\delta y} = \frac{2y}{9}$$
$$\frac{\partial f_{2}}{\delta x} = 2x-2,\frac{\partial f_{2}}{\delta y} = 1$$

Are these correct?  I think I just need another pair of eyes to verify, as I'm not sure where else I'm going wrong.

Comment: The functions you choose for Newtons method should be such that $f_1(x,y) = 0$, $f_2(x,y) = 0$ when $x,y$ solves your system of equations. This means that we can take $f_1(x,y) = x^2/16 + y^2/9 - 1$ and $f_2(x,y) = x^2 - 2x - 4 - y$ (which it kind off seems you have done, but your notation for defining $f_1,f_2$ is not good). If you do this you get your result modulo the mistake pointed out in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

These are equations, not functions. You can turn them into functions by moving everything to one side and interpreting that as the function on that side being equated to $0$. But if that's what you mean, you should have $\partial f_2/\partial y=-1$.

(You can get the partial derivative symbol $\partial$ using `\partial`.)